# simple dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i did not found simple dropdown list .

i'm new in mvc3

this part create and fill :      ListMonitoringLicenseModelList = new List();

i fill this objectsList  in another part and use it to fill MonitoringLicenseModelList

objectsList = new List(...fill objectsList...);

```
    List<MonitoringLicenseModel>MonitoringLicenseModelList = new List<MonitoringLicenseModel>();
        foreach (object o in objectsList)
        {
            string[] tmpString = o.ToString().Split('@');

            int i = 0;

            monitoringLicenseModel = new MonitoringLicenseModel();
            monitoringLicenseModel.MonitoringID =Convert.ToInt32(tmpString[i++]);
            monitoringLicenseModel.LicenseUI = tmpString[i++];
           MonitoringLicenseModelList.Add(monitoringLicenseModel);
        }
```

public ActionResult SchedulesIndex()
        {

```
        return View(MonitoringLicenseModelList);
     }
```

how can i write dropdownlist to show this

```
                 name                value

            MonitoringID   =     LicenseUI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model List<MonitoringLicenseModel>
...
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedMotoringID", 
    new SelectList(Model, "MonitoringID", "LicenseUI")
)
```